# What would be the best way to express the term 'master', as in a master of some sport?

Tags: word-choice, usage, phrase-requests, sports

For example, 'a tennis master'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for adjectives to describe skill here's a few:

> 上手【じょうず】 (generally speaking) *good at* ~
>
> 巧妙【こうみょう】 *mysteriously skillful at* ~
>
> ～の天才【てんさい】 *a genius in* ~
>
> 熟練した【じゅくれんした】 This one is my favourite, it has the meaning of *practised to perfection*.

Some examples:

> 私はテニスが上手です。
> I am good at tennis.
>
> あのテニス選手は巧妙です。
> That tennis player is skillful.
>
> テニスの天才
> a genius in tennis
>
> テニスの熟練者
> an expert at tennis
>
> 熟練したテニス選手
> an expert tennis player

Comment: From @Samurai Soul's question, I'd say the word he is looking for might be '選手【せんしゅ】' (I see it in your examples, but not in the list of words above them).

Comment: Just curious if マスター itself is used anywhere outside of 完全マスター.

Comment: @Dave `選手` just means a player. It does not mean that it is a master.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, as @sawa pointed out, 選手 on its own is not enough. I meant: **qualifier** + 選手 like 優れた選手

Comment: Regarding 上手: It can easily sound arrogant to use 上手 to describe yourself this way, which is why you'll hear 得意 more often. Of course 上手ではない and 上手になりたい are perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, 選手is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an outstanding player. These are good suggestions - I like 天才. I think that fits well.

Comment: 天才 for a reasonably "normal" (if particularly good) tennis player sounds really weird to me. It is much more commonly used for *intellectual* genius. Applied to sport, it would have the ring of "one in a million", definitely stronger than "expert".

Answer (score 5):

I think for sports, the word `プロ` 'professional' is usually used to refer to a skilled player, even if that person is not actually a professional. For Japanese sports like judo or sumo, there are specific words that describe what level the player is at.

Comment: +1 Oh, of course! I should have thought of that. I use プロ myself all the time in english and Japanese. Good one.

Answer (score 2):

At least for the taiko video game it is 達人 (たつじん) meaning "master / expert" not sure if this carries over to sports

Comment: Krillin used 達人 to describe Jackie Chun as an expert fighter in Dragon Ball, for what that's worth